# How to draw simple 3D model using Android Studio, Vuforia and OpenGL

Tags: android, android-studio, 3d, opengl-es, vuforia

I have a fully functional iOS app, and now I am working on the Android version in Android Studio. 
The app is not a 3D-game, it uses the normal listview etc., but in one activity the app uses Augmented Reality.
I have chosen to use Vuforia (to get more devices' than ARCore+ARKit) and bought this simple 3D model.

https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/blend-gift/977474

Now I just want to show my own model on my Vuforia Image Marker. Easy! I thought ...

Vuforia uses OpenGL to render their 3D-model. It is a teapot (https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Image-Target-Guide) and it looks like the class it needs to render the teapot looks like this:

```
public class Teapot extends MeshObject {

private Buffer mVertBuff;
private Buffer mTexCoordBuff;
private Buffer mNormBuff;
private Buffer mIndBuff;

private int indicesNumber = 0;
private int verticesNumber = 0;

 public Teapot()
    {
        setVerts();
        setTexCoords();
        setNorms();
        setIndices();
    }  

 private void setVerts()
    {
            double[] TEAPOT_VERTS = { 11.222200, 0.110300, 20.030291, 10.302300, ect. } 
        mVertBuff = fillBuffer(TEAPOT_VERTS);
        verticesNumber = TEAPOT_VERTS.length / 3;
        }

 private void setTexCoords()
    {
        double[] TEAPOT_TEX_COORDS = { 0.608828, 0.354913, 0.609037, 0.414650, ect. }

          mTexCoordBuff = fillBuffer(TEAPOT_TEX_COORDS);


    }

 private void setNorms()
    {
        double[] TEAPOT_NORMS = { -0.964496, 0.067011, -0.255454, -0.865037, ect. } 

        mNormBuff = fillBuffer(TEAPOT_NORMS);


           }

private void setIndices()
    {
        short[] TEAPOT_INDICES = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4, 8, 9, ect. }

        mIndBuff = fillBuffer(TEAPOT_INDICES);
        indicesNumber = TEAPOT_INDICES.length;
        } 
}
```

So i thought - aha - if I could just find the Verts, TexCoords, Norms and Indices of my 3D-model. I could paste them here, and then paint my awesome Christmas gift, instead of the teapot.

I have the 3D-model in:

- 3D Studio Project
- Collada
- OBJ
- Other textures
- FBX

And I also have blender (but almost zero blender-skills). After a long time searching I though that if I could convert the model to a j-son file. I could get the right inputs to draw it. But the created j-son file is veeeeery big! And when I paste the numbers I get from the file, the app crashes with: error: code too large - which I of course do not want :-(

So now im am stuck once again... Maybe my gift is to big? Or my way of doing this is totally wrong?

I think that the Android Studios creaters should make 3D-importing and rendering easier - But that doesn't help me now!

It is just a simple 3D present, and I want it where the simple 3D teapot is.

Comment: Did you found any work around for this ? i am facing the same issue while converting 3d object to java mesh vurofia doesn't support firect 3d models